# What is the meaning of っ on its own

Tags: translation, manga, anime

Does it mean Tch or does it have another meaning ??
[image]
Like in here.

Answer (score 7):

In a light novel, manga or such, 「……っ！」 without any preceding kana describes the speaker is speechless or breathless for a moment. Usually it expresses a strong surprise, anger, confusion or any "breathtaking" feelings.

"Tch" to express one's irritation is usually [ちっ or ちぇっ](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%83%81%E3%82%A7).